# How do I format a grammar rule that requies two tokens to be equal?

Tags: parsing, yacc

How can I write a Yacc grammar that matches two tokens?  For example:

```
START some_random_id
stuff stuff stuff
END some_random_id
```

I would like to make the requirement that the some_random_id matches at both places to match the entire block. So it would be something like:

```
block <- START ID block_body END ID
```

with the additional requirement that both IDs are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as `some_random_id` is drawn from a set of arbitrary size, this is not possible to do with grammar rules alone.  There is a classic mathematical proof of this. You can only do it with parser action code that checks whether the `id`s are the same.  But this is not very hard.  Define the `yylval` union to have a field `id_string` that is filled in by the scanner.  Then you'll have something like:

```
%union {
  char *id_string;
  ...
} 
%token <id_string> ID KW_START KW_END 
%%
...
block : KW_START ID stuff KW_END ID  { 
    if (strcmp($2.id_string, $5.id_string) != 0) YYERROR; }
```

Comment: +1 We should merge our answers.  I believe we are saying the same thing (for [statguy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1457093/statguy) info).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll add your union declaration (except you forgot the % ;-)

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. I'm actually not using yacc but ply (yacc for Python). I'm essentially doing the same thing as what you guys proposed.